# How to access GitLab CI/CD Variable in Ruby Recipes?

Tags: ruby, gitlab, chef-infra

I have declared some variables in Gitlab -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables.

I want to access these variables in ruby (.rb) files for chef cookbook recipes.

I have declared a variable named "TEST_VARIABLE" in settings as:
Gitlab -> Settings -> CI/CD -> Variables :- Key =  TEST_VARIABLE, Value = TEST_VALUE

I have tried accessing them in the below format in the ruby(.rb) recipes.
$TEST_VARIABLE, ${TEST_VARIABLE},TEST_VARIABLE, #{TEST_VARIABLE} and ENV['TEST_VARIABLE']
But nothing works, all returns blank or nil value.

Please let me know how to access these variables in the .rb file.

Answer (score 0):

I dont think that you can use pipeline variables in normal source code. Maybe you can set in your script section a shell environment variable and access it in your ruby code.

```
script:
 - export TEST_VARIABLE=$TEST_VARIABLE
```

Comment: Good answer but it could be worded in a clearer way without ambiguity

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the variables to the ruby script when you call it.

```
script:
 - ./rubyscript $TEST_VARIABLE
```